# I don't think there is an inplace operation, but an inplace operation error occurs

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

The following error occurs:

```
C:\Users\D3\anaconda3\envs\kittimos\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py:199: UserWarning:
Error detected in CudnnRnnBackward0. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "d:/anaconda/myproject/MYPROJECT77_4class.py", line 328, in <module>
    lstm_output, (hidden_state, cell_state) = lstm_module(backbone_output_flattened, (hidden_state, cell_state))
  File "C:\Users\D3\anaconda3\envs\kittimos\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "d:/anaconda/myproject/MYPROJECT77_4class.py", line 190, in forward
    out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
  File "C:\Users\D3\anaconda3\envs\kittimos\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\D3\anaconda3\envs\kittimos\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 775, in forward
    self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional, self.batch_first)
  File "C:\Users\D3\anaconda3\envs\kittimos\lib\site-packages\torch\fx\traceback.py", line 57, in format_stack
    return traceback.format_stack()
 (Triggered internally at C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\torch\csrc\autograd\python_anomaly_mode.cpp:119.)
  allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/anaconda/myproject/MYPROJECT77_4class.py", line 358, in <module>
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
  File "C:\Users\D3\anaconda3\envs\kittimos\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor.py", line 489, in backward
    self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
  File "C:\Users\D3\anaconda3\envs\kittimos\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 199, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [2048, 80352]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

First, I annotated each part to see where the problem occurs.

All parts related to lstm have been annotated. The existing code was the one in which the output of the lstm network was transmitted to the fully connected layer.
The error seems to have disappeared after changing the tensor entered in the lstm to a fully connected layer without passing through the lstm. But I'm not sure.

I also checked if there was an inplace operation in other areas, but I found that there were no operations such as `+=`, `-=`.

Finally, I tried using `inplace=False` in ReLU as an answer to a similar question in Stack Overflow, but it was still the same.

The code is below. (I think the lstm part is the problem, but I'll upload other parts just in case.)

```
class UpsampleBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, scale_factor):
        super(UpsampleBlock, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=scale_factor, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)  

class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size).to(device)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size).to(device)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size , num_classes)

        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(1, -1)  # Flatten the input tensor
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x


class PointPillarsFeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=9, out_channels=64):
        super(PointPillarsFeatureExtractor, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1)
        self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.batchnorm(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        # Max pooling over the points (N dimension)
        x, _ = torch.max(x, dim=2)
        return x
   
class CNNBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, num_layers):
        super(CNNBlock, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(*[
            nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels if i == 0 else out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size,
                          stride=2 if i == 0 else 1, padding=padding),
                #nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
                nn.ReLU()
            )
            for i in range(num_layers)
        ])

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)


class UpsampleBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, scale_factor):
        super(UpsampleBlock, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=scale_factor, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)   


class PointPillarsBackbone(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=64, C=64, S=2):
        super(PointPillarsBackbone, self).__init__()

        self.block1 = CNNBlock(in_channels, C, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, num_layers=1)
        self.block2 = CNNBlock(C, 2 * C, kernel_size=3, stride=2 , padding=1, num_layers=1)
        self.block3 = CNNBlock(2 * C, 4 * C, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, num_layers=1)

        self.up1 = UpsampleBlock(in_channels,  C//2 , scale_factor=1/4)
        self.up2 = UpsampleBlock(2 * C,   C//2, scale_factor=1/2)
        self.up3 = UpsampleBlock(4 * C,   C//2, scale_factor=1)
    def forward(self, x):
        block1_out = self.block1(x)
        block2_out = self.block2(block1_out)
        block3_out = self.block3(block2_out)

        up1_out = self.up1(block1_out)
        up2_out = self.up2(block2_out)
        up3_out = self.up3(block3_out)

        concat_features = torch.cat((up1_out, up2_out, up3_out), dim=1)
        return concat_features



class LSTMModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers=1, batch_first=True):
        super(LSTMModule, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=batch_first)
       
    def forward(self, x, hidden=None):
        if hidden is None:
            out, hidden = self.lstm(x)
        else:
            out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)

        return out, hidden




for i in range(0, 401):
    filename = f"{i:03d}.bin"
    filepath = os.path.join(folder, filename)

    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        tensor = process_bin_file(filepath)
        tensor = torch.Tensor(tensor)
        tensor = tensor.permute(1, 0, 2).to(device)  
        features = feature_extractor(tensor)
        features = features.permute(1, 0)
        features = features.unsqueeze(0).permute(0, 1, 2)


        x_indices = (((tensor[7, :, 0] - point_cloud_range[0]) // voxel_size[0]).long())
        y_indices = (((tensor[8, :, 0] - point_cloud_range[1]) // voxel_size[1]).long())


        pseudo_image = scatter_features_module(features, x_indices, y_indices)
        backbone_output = backbone_module(pseudo_image)
        print("backbone_output shape  is !!!!! :",  backbone_output.shape)

        backbone_output_flattened = backbone_output.view(1, 1, -1)
        print("backbone_output_flattened shape  is !!!!! :",  backbone_output_flattened.shape)

        lstm_output, (hidden_state, cell_state) = lstm_module(backbone_output_flattened, (hidden_state, cell_state))


        if i >= sequence_length - 1:
            hidden_state = hidden_state[:, 1:, :].clone()
            cell_state = cell_state[:, 1:, :].clone()

            hidden_state = torch.cat([hidden_state, lstm_output[:, -1, :].unsqueeze(1)], dim=1).clone()
            cell_state = torch.cat([cell_state, lstm_output[:, -1, :].unsqueeze(1)], dim=1).clone()
        else:
            hidden_state = lstm_output[:, -1, :].unsqueeze(1).clone()
            cell_state = lstm_output[:, -1, :].unsqueeze(1).clone()
        output = classifier(lstm_output)

        predicted_class = torch.argmax(output[0, 1:]) + 1

        # Calculate the loss and update parameters
        gt_label = torch.tensor([ground_truth[i]], dtype=torch.long).to(device)
        loss = criterion(output, gt_label)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Despite finding the problem you should absolutely 100% still [edit] your post to show a [mcve] instead of a huge program, most lines of which have nothing to do with the error, so that future visitors can actually tell whether or not they're looking at the same problem they are having. Without that, this is a case of "you solved your own problem without anyone's help, so everyone else can too, and this question doesn't need to exist".

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I made a mistake.
It was a problem caused by the update of `cell_state` and `hidden_state` and I solved it by adding a few lines of code.

```
    hidden = (hidden_state.detach(), cell_state.detach())
    lstm_output2, (hidden_state2, cell_state2) = 
    lstm_module(backbone_output_flattened, hidden)
```